# Merge [front-controller] and [frontcontroller]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I would suggest merging [front-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/front-controller/info) and [frontcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/frontcontroller/info) as they refer to the same thing.

Description from their respective pages:

[front-controller]

> The Front Controller Pattern provides a centralized entry point for handling requests in web applications.
>   Front controllers are often used in web applications to implement workflows. While not strictly required, it is much easier to control navigation across a set of related pages (for instance, multiple pages might be used in an online purchase) from a front controller than it is to make the individual pages responsible for navigation.

[frontcontroller]

> A structural (and partitioning) design pattern that provides a centralized entry point for handling requests and is an extension to the model-view-controller design pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[frontcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frontcontroller) is now syn'd and merged into [front-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/front-controller)